# Twilio Say and Gather in same Twiml

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

New to Twilio, I have a simple Python program that initiates an outbound call from Twilio that points to URL:
    http://twimlets.com/menu?Message=Press%20one%20when%20you%20hear%20this&Options%5B1%5D=http%3A%2F%2Ftwimlets.com%2Fmessage%3FMessage%255B0%255D%3DCongrats%252C%2520you%2520pressed%25201%26&
with:

```
<Response>
<Gather numDigits="1">
<Say>Press one when you hear this</Say>
</Gather>
<Redirect/>
</Response>
```

when caller presses 1 it redirects the caller to:

```
<Response>
<Say>Congrats, you pressed 1</Say>
</Response>
```

How can I capture the Gather input as I need to report based on if caller pressed 1, I don't see any options to do that during the create method.

Here is all I am doing: 
    call = client.api.account.calls.create(to="+XXXXXXXXXXX", from_=Twilio_DID, url=twimlets)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you need to record the numbers that users press then I recommend not using Twimlets to build this application.

Instead, I would build the entire application yourself in Python. There is a tutorial on [how to gather user input via keypad in Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-python) that will likely help you out.

The key is that when you create a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) you should set an `action` url in the attributes. When the user enters the digits you are expecting, Twilio will make a request to that url and it will include a [`Digits` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action) in the body of the request. You can use that parameter to save what the user chose and direct the call onwards.

Comment: Thank you, but I am confused as to how can I generate an outbound call and tie the gather() method to the outbound call from Twilio as it appears to be more for an inbound call.

Comment: When you make an outbound call you provide the to number, the from number and a URL. That URL will be requested when the call connects and your application should respond with TwiML, which can include `<Gather>`. Outbound calls act the same as inbound calls, except that you initiate the call.

Comment: Thank you again, apologies for being slow on this, I still don't know how my program will collect what is defined under Gather, according to docs I can collect digits with Gather, so assume I answer the Twilio call and press digit 5, how do I capture that in my program?

Comment: On the `<Gather>` tag you set the `action` attribute to a URL that you control. When the user enters the digits on the phone Twilio then sends an HTTP request to that URL with the digits entered as the `Digits` parameter in the request. Your program needs to receive that HTTP request and retrieve the digits. I recommend going through the Python tutorial I linked in the answer as that will make it all clearer for you.